# Python Pandas - Creating a new column using currency_converter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (dfFF) like this:

```
   Sector   Country           Currency    Amount     Fund Start Year
0  Public     USA                USD        22000      2016
0  Private    Hong Kong          HKD        42000      2015
...
```

I want to create a new column that converts the `currency/amount/fund start year` into Euros and then to GBP (currency_converter only converts to everything to Euros or back hence why I am not converting straight to GBP). I want the currency rate for the year that the funding took place.

I am using the template code given by the website:
https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
from datetime import date
c = CurrencyConverter()  
c.convert(100, 'EUR', 'USD', date=date(2013, 3, 21))
```

I want to use the 1st of January for every year to make it consistent, so I have tried doing the following:

```
c = CurrencyConverter()
dfFF['Value'] = (c.convert(dfFF['Amount'],dfFF['Currency'],
'EUR',date=date(dfFF['Fund Start Year'],1,1)))
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Although I feel that my solution isnt the best way of doing this.

Any suggestions? Even if I just get it into EUROS, and then I can do the same to convert it to GBP would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have  create a function for converting currency using data of a row:

```
def currency_convertor(row):
 amount = row['amount']
 curr = row['Currency'], 
 date_r = row['Fund Start Year']
 new_curr = c.convert(amount,curr,'EUR',date=date(date_r,1,1))
 return new_curr
```

and then apply it to dataframe:

```
dfFF['EUR_new'] = dfFF.apply(currency_convert, axis=1) # make sure to set axis=1
```

#### General Version

```
def currency_convertor(row,new_currency='EUR'):
 amount = row['amount']
 curr = row['Currency']
 date_r = row['Fund Start Year']
 new_curr = c.convert(amount,curr,new_currency,date=date(date_r,1,1))
 return new_curr

dfFF['new_currency'] = dfFF.apply(lambda x: currency_convertor(x,new_currency="GBP"), axis=1)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!... I should have realised it should have been a function. I will try it now and will feedback ASAP!

Comment: Is that last statement correct? I changed it to 'currency_convertor' as as 'currency_convert' was not defined, but I am getitng a 'TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer' error?

Comment: I converted the year to int64 to make sure it was not that, the rest of the columns are objects, so not sure if that helps

Comment: Ahhh, your code works, it was that 'amount' should have been 'Amount' and the other point above.... although GBP is not supported apparently so I will have to fix that! Thank you again :)

Comment: Hmmm... weird. GBP is a supported currency so not sure why it isnt working. This is the error: ValueError: ("('GBP',) is not a supported currency", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: can you write here what is your function when you want convert to "GBP"

Comment: I did some further testing. And it throws an error regardless of currency. So just had 'ValueError: ("('USD',) is not a supported currency", 'occurred at index 0')'

Comment: I am using your function (I have tried both), and then, I do: dfFF['EUR_new'] = dfFF.apply(currency_convertor, axis=1)

Comment: Check the edited answer and tell me whats the result.

Comment: I am still getting the same error :/.... dont worry Mehdi, if it doesnt work, it doesnt work. I can try and think of a different way to do it. I dont want to waste your time. Thank you for all your help though!

Comment: FIXED IT! You have a comma after the curr = row['Currency'], ...... could you remove it please? and I will mark your answer as accepted. Oh, could you also change 'currency_convert' to 'currency_convertor' in the last statement :).... thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for those typos I just type the code in the stackoverflow and didn't notice to `,`.